# How can I LEFT JOIN a table and COUNT the rows?

Tags: mysql

I want to list my projects and the amount of posts each project has:

```
     `projects`                `posts`
------------------     ------------------
| `id`  | `name` |     | `id`  | `name`  |
------------------     ------------------
|   1   | Cat    |     |   1   |    Cat  |
|   2   | Dog    |     |   2   |    Cat  |
|   3   | Bird   |     |   3   |    Dog  |
|   4   | Frog   |     ------------------
------------------



$projects = $db->query('SELECT *,
    COUNT(posts.*) AS posts
    FROM projects
    LEFT JOIN posts ON projects.name=posts.name 
  ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



    foreach($projects as $row) {
       echo "Project ".$id." has ".$posts ".posts.".<br>"; 
    }
```

So as a result I expect:

```
Project 1 has 2 posts.
Project 2 has 1 posts.
Project 3 has 0 posts.
Project 4 has 0 posts.
```

But I get an error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '*) AS posts,

So I changed `posts.*` into `posts.id`

But then my result is:

```
Project 1 has 3 posts.
```

I am actually now confused how to achieve the result I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was raised because of count(po.*) you must count for one column only inside of a count() function.

So, we want to find out how many times will find the 'name' column in posts table for a corresponding id column in projects table so we should count posts.name from posts joined with projects.

We need left join because we want also find out if it does not have corespondent (count(po.name) =0))

The query below will do the job:

```
SELECT p.*,COUNT(po.name) AS posts
    FROM projects p
    left join posts po on p.name = po.name
    group by p.id
```

You can check here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e9d4b/4